# Ajax not working on form when loaded via ajax PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load form from server side using Ajax and PHP. All works fine but when im doing an ajax call when the form is submitted, the form data is not being picked up.

I have tried moving the ajax call in and out of document.ready and tried placing at the end of body. I tried replacing form.on(submit,..) with a function and nothing seems to work.

Here is my index.html

```
  <head>

    <script>

      $(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajax({
          url:'loadTimesheets.php',
          method: 'GET',
          success:function(data){
            $('#myDiv').html(data);
          }
        });
      });


      $('form').on('submit',function(event){
        // event.preventDefault();
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $('#mypara').html(form_data);
        $.ajax({
          url:'insertTime.php',
          method: 'POST',
          data: form_data,
          success:function(data){
            $('#mypara').html(data);
          }
        });
      });

    </script>

  </head>

<body>
    <div>
      <p id="mypara"> Change this</p>

    </div>
<div class="jumbotron" id="myDiv">

</div>

<script>


    // $('form').on('submit',function(event){
    //   // event.preventDefault();
    //   var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    //   $('#mypara').html(form_data);
    //   $.ajax({
    //     url:'insertTime.php',
    //     method: 'POST',
    //     data: form_data,
    //     success:function(data){
    //       $('#mypara').html(data);
    //     }
    //   });
    // });

    function insertTime(event){
      var form_data = $(this).serialize();
      $('#mypara').html(form_data);
      $.ajax({
        url:'insertTime.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        success:function(data){
          $('#mypara').html(data);
        }
      });
    }

</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is the loadTimesheets.php which is called to load the form into index.html

```
<?php

  echo "<table class='table table-hover'>";

  echo "<form method='post' id='user_form'>
            <tr>
            <td> Gani </td>
            <td> PHP </td>
            <td><input type='text' name='time[]' value=0></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='time[]' value=0></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='time[]' value=0></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='time[]' value=0></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='time[]' value=0></td>
            <td><input type='submit' value='submit'>
            </tr></form>";
// <td><input type='submit' value='submit' onsubmit='insertTime(event)'>
  echo "</table>";



 ?>
```

And this is my insertTime.php which is called when a form is submitted

```
<?php

  $total_time = 0;
  $sql = "
          UPDATE timesheet
          SET time_period_1 = ". $_POST['time'][0]. ",
          time_period_2 = ". $_POST['time'][1]. ",
          time_period_3 = ". $_POST['time'][2]. ",
          time_period_4 = ". $_POST['time'][3]. ",
          time_period_5 = ". $_POST['time'][4]. ",
          total_time = ". $total_time. ";";

echo $sql;

 ?>
```

If I just load the forms directly by making index as php file and loading inline using require, there are no issues with form data submission. 
Please help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the form is being loaded via AJAX the jQuery is not aware of the form elements because those are "gathered" during original page load. You may have to change your event delegation to `$('body').on('submit', 'form', function(event){...`

Comment: if you are loading dynamic content like this any event listeners registered when the page first loads will not be aware of the new content when it is finally inserted into the DOM ( though I don't use jQuery so it might be smarter than that ) - one option would be to use `event delegation` and register an event listener on the parent node `#mypara` and check the event triggered against that?!

Comment: Incidentally - the HTML you posted in the question is NOT valid. A form must either be entirely within a table-cell ( `td` ) or the entire table must be within the form... you cannot straddle element boundaries like this for it to remain valid - certain elements permit certain child elements

Comment: Also worth noting is the fact that this code is (potentially) wide open to SQL injection. The query does not get executed in the code shown so it is safe in that respect - use a `prepared statement` with bound parameters in place of directly embedded POST variables

Comment: @RamRaider, thank you for your suggestions. I removed table elements and used some bootstrap instead. Was using it initially for alignment. Should look into prepared statement as well.

Comment: Wow!! That was quick. Thank you @JayBlanchard, that worked